# How to display readonly field with 3 attributes while taking user input in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

The user will select currency,write amount, and select time(hour,day,month,year). I need to make a functional component which takes all these values provided by user and displays a read-only value in 1 box (as show).
[image]

The user input box is supposed to look like this
[image]

Also, It would be very helpful if anybody can style it similarly or atleast tell how can I. (using CSS, scss, antD, tailwind anything).

P.S: Don't avoid mentioning the placeholder.

Comment: My code is pretty broken but, Link to the codebase I am trying [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-stitch-eci77z?file=/src/ReadOnlyComponent.tsx:379-402)

Comment: Can you provide a detailed description of problem? Like what is the exact functionality you want? I am not clear with the question!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it step by step. Create what you want in the simplest/ugliest way possible. It doesn't matter how it looks, if it works it is enough.

1. You need to create a component which renders a select for currency, select for time, an input for value and a `div` to display the currency symbol.
2. Use javascript to change the currency symbol when user selects a currency using the select. Your component should be able to handle `value` and `onChange` that receives from the parent component.
3. All you have to do is to use CSS. Read mui documentation for components and inspect elements to see how you should change styles. You can also take a look at mui github code.

Comment: I am a beginner, facing difficulty in creating a component which renders all these. Can you please write in code, if you may, I'll be really thankful.